# Why c# recognizes the name of my SQL Server like a unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

The name of my SQL server is: SEVEN-PC\SQLEXPRESS. But I have a trouble when I try to create the Connection String for c#.

C# recognizes the '\' like an unrecognized escape sequence. I tried to solve using double '\', a '@' before the string and using `Convert.ToChar(92)`, but always obtain this string with a double '\':

```
protected string cadenaConexion = "Data Source=SEVEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AlquilerPeliculas;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Does exist some way to create the string without change the SQL server's name?

A link to the image with the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0eWU.jpg

Comment: This connection string looks okey to me. What is your question exactly? Where did you see this double quotes? In your debugger?

Comment: "but always obtain this string with a double '\'" - where are you seeing that string again? Because things like some of the debugger displays will "helpfully" re-escape single slashes. So the string in fact contains a single \ but, depending on where you look, it may be *displayed* with two.

Comment: Do you actually get an error or did you assume that you may have an error? The connection string has no problems and the behavior you describe is normal and logical - otherwise you wouldn't be able to view characters like `\n` or `\t` in the debugger

Comment: When I write the string: ...Data Source=SEVEN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;.. I can't compile it, because the compiler takes the '\' like an unrecognized escape sequence and don't let me compile. I atacched a link with a screen of where see the string with double '\'

Comment: Just escape the slash then as you already posted. If you include an escape character in the string, you have to escape it as well. That's how strings work in C, C++, Java, C#. The compiler didn't mistake `\` for an unrecognized sequence, it sees a `\S` sequence which it doesn't recognize.

Comment: That screenshot does not show an error.

Comment: @SebastiánJoséM - that screen shot shows exactly what I was talking about. The string only contains *one* \ character, but the debugger display is re-escaping it for you. Just go ahead with that code and *use* that connection string.

Comment: If there is not the trouble, surely I have other connection problem. Thank you very much for all. I'll investigate tomorrow.